# How can I find anomalies in features based on difference between true and predicted targets?

Tags: regression, anomaly-detection

Generally the problem is the following : there is target (efficiency of mobile stations). The goal is to find stations which underperform and highlight the reasons of that. Other than this it is desired to find means to improve overall efficiency. One of the problems is that there are features highly correlated with the target (for example the target efficiency is strongly connected with traffic and utilization, so low target would most probably mean that the traffic is low, but the point is to find out why it is low.) The current way to do that is the following: firstly we remove strongly correlated features with target, then we train model to predict the target. For those objects which predicted target is equal to true target we perform shapley explaining to see which features are important to look at. For those stations which predicted target is greater than true target (so model sees the potential to improve efficiency of these stations) we train models with features as targets, trying to find one which will be different from true. The question is, is this approach good? Are there ways to improve it? Maybe there are other efficient methods to solve such problem?

Answer (score 0):

The approach looks wrong.
Your final model input is binary while output is a list of features.

I will prepare data. Input will be features that describe efficiency of station. Output will be whether efficiency can be increased or not. Use Shaply to determine factors influencing decision.

Comment: There is no "final model". There are initial model to predict target and models to predict features (1 per model).
Also, what do you mean by "whether efficiency can be increased or not"? There is no such given data

Comment: what is 1 per model ? Do you mean 1 model predicts 1 feature . So there are multiple models like that ?

Comment: Yes, the current approach suggests that.

Comment: Since traffic is highly correlated feature with target, find out features correlated with traffic. Remove traffic. Now you can see importance of other factors.